# Как повернуть текст под углом (pillow)?

Tags: python, pillow

Всем привет!
Хочу перeвернуть текст на 80 градусов, как это можно осуществить?
Вот есть код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab, ImageFont, ImageDraw

txt = Image.open("screen.png")
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 36)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
d.text((740,430), 'hello world', font=fnt, fill=('#1f6992')) #значения "740" 
и "430" - это значения по иксу и игрику, а как по углу задать?
txt.save("file.png", "PNG")
```

спасибо

Comment: рисуешь на прозрачном слое текст, потом поворачивай и наклыдывай на исходник.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/245892/5741205

Comment: `image.rotate(angle)` не пробовали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Текст, который мы будем рисовать, и шрифт к нему:

```
label = 'Hello!'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
```

Для удобства зафиксируем высоту строки, так как Pillow её меняет в зависимости от текста, что может помешать поворачиванию. В частности, высота текста `A` — 33 пикселя, а высота текста `q` — уже 40 пикселей из-за торчащей вниз палочки. Чтобы получить точную высоту всей строки целиком, в которую влезут любые буквы, воспользуемся почему-то недокументированным методом `getmetrics`:

```
line_height = sum(font.getmetrics())  # в нашем случае 33 + 8 = 41
```

Теперь отрисуем текст на отдельной чистой картинке. Здесь применим небольшую хитрость: картинка будет в оттенках серого и обозначать альфа-канал. Чёрный цвет (0) — полная прозрачность, белый (255) — полная непрозрачность. Чтобы картинка была размером с наш текст, получим его ширину с помощью метода `getsize`, а высоту возьмём из нашего постоянного `line_height`.

```
# Создаём пустую чёрную картинку
fontimage = Image.new('L', (font.getsize(label)[0], line_height))
# И рисуем на ней белый текст
ImageDraw.Draw(fontimage).text((0, 0), label, fill=255, font=font)
```

(Заменой 255 на другое число можно регулировать прозрачность текста.)

Результат:

[image]

Теперь повернём его. Нам нужно добавить `expand=True`, чтобы размеры картинки увеличились так, чтобы повёрнутый текст влезал.

```
fontimage = fontimage.rotate(80, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
```

[image] [image]

*Слева хороший результат с `expand`, справа плохой без `expand` для сравнения*

Теперь получившуюся картинку можно наложить на оригинал.

```
orig = Image.open('original.png')
orig.paste((255, 0, 0), box=(0, 0), mask=fontimage)
```

Первым аргументом указывается картинка, которую накладываем. Вместо неё можно указать цвет, что я и сделал: это RGB, обозначающий красный цвет.

Второй аргумент при скармливании ему кортежа с двумя элементами обозначает место, в которое будет вставлена картинка. Важно помнить, что по этим координатам будет расположен верхний левый угол вставляемой картинки, а не, например, начала текста; если нужно вставить текст над какой-либо точкой, придётся проводить дополнительные вычисления координат. Здесь я просто пихаю всё в левый верхний угол.

Третий аргумент — маска, согласно которой обе картинки будут смешиваться. В качестве неё я и использую чёрно-белый повёрнутый текст: чёрный цвет — полная прозрачность, белый — непрозрачность.

Результат:

[image]

*[Оригинал](https://liamwhite1.deviantart.com/art/Background-Apples-490598358) до вставки*

[image]

*После вставки*

Comment: я уже разобрался, но все равно спасибо)