# Как убрать дефект на изображении?

Tags: python, pil

Всем привет!
После выполнения этого кода:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab, ImageFont, ImageDraw 
tatras = Image.open("screen.png") #открываем изображение
rotated = tatras.rotate(-30, resample=Image.BICUBIC) #поворачиваем его на -30 градусов
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36) 
d = ImageDraw.Draw(rotated)
d.text((500, 500), 'hello', font=font, fill=('#1f6992')) #накладываем текст
rotated1 = rotated.rotate(30, resample=Image.BICUBIC) #поворачиваем на 30 градусов
rotated1.save('tatras_rotated.png', quality=90)  #сохраняем
```

изображение как-то некорректно отображается, это видимо потому что я произвел повторный переворот на 30 градусов, но этот повторный поворот необходим (для отображения текста в кривом виде), подскажите пожалуйста как исправить этот дефект.

Вот само изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо

Comment: Не понял смысла всех этих манипуляций, можно же проще: 1) Создаём пустую картинку и рисуем на ней текст; 2) Поворачиваем картинку с текстом; 3) Накладываем картинку с текстом на исходную картинку

Comment: ц.. точно!)) а не подскажешь как одну фотку на другую наложить?)

Comment: В принципе всё есть в документации: [раз](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste), [два](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.alpha_composite). А полноценный ответ с примером у меня пока нет времени написать

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: ...хотя вообще то же самое уже говорили [в старом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722163), хех

Comment: в общем сделал как ты сказал, но после наложения пустой фотки с текстом на другую фотку, она наложилась не в прозрачном виде, я ниже фото отдельно прикреплю, для наглядности